# Generate Signed Bundle: Errors while building Bundle file. 'other' has different root

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

The following error occur when I tried to Generate Signed Bundle. Note: Error occurs after I updated my android studio 3.6.3 to version 4.0 and Gradle build to 6.1.1.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:signReleaseBundle'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
>   'other' has different root

Comment: try ```File > Invalidate Caches/Restart```

Comment: tried but it didn't work.

Comment: When generating SignedAPK it works fine. But when I try to generate SignedAPKBundle it gives above mentioned error.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Same here. Looks like it does not like to build to another drive letter.
i.e. Key store path is on D: and destination folder on E: and I get the message 'other' has different root. Note that the file seems to be produced on E: anyway.
When I change destination folder to D: it's all ok.

Comment: I spend whole day troubleshooting and finding the problem. This works for me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: This works like a charm. Why should Android Studio do such a thing?

Comment: To clarify the extracted app bundle needs to be on the same drive as the application not the key.

Comment: This Worked for me thanks a lot. but why this type of criteria they have added.

Comment: Worked. But it doesn't make any sense to me why it doesn't produce AAB at desired location. Comment if anyone have idea. Just curious.

Comment: I am facing the same issue and I am exporting aab file to the same drive but still facing the same issue any idea?

Comment: Damn, Google... do all your employees have a single drive?
Thanks for the explanation. It works!

Comment: Really?! ... Such a ridiculous mistake. Thanks for your answer. It worked for me.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. I have my build, keystore and save location on same drive different folders but it still does not work. Also tried invalidating cache and restarting. Nothing working.

Comment: Just adding to my previous comment. I am facing an absolutely opposite thing. When I have same drive letter say D: for keystore and destination folder I get error. I changed destination forlder C: drive and it generated output aab files without any error. There seems to be some other reason for this error not the diff. drive letters.

Comment: Ex: if your project is somewhere in drive "D:..." then your bundle file location must be somewhere in drive "D:...".

Comment: Yes, it was the destination folder. thanks.

Answer (score 21):

This works for `APK` but for `AAB` You must have the **keystore** file and generated **APK FOLDER** on the same drive.

Answer (score 7):

For generating .aab bundle file, your bundle file destination must be in the same drive as where your project is located. For .aab files the key store location is not relevant.

Ex: if your project is somewhere in drive "D:..." then your bundle file location must be somewhere in drive "D:...".

Answer (score 4):

The project and Keystore file should have the same drive otherwise this error will arise.

Comment: This worked for me

Answer (score 2):

I had previously, temporarily had my project on drive E, I moved it back to drive C, got the **'other' has different root** message.
Solution for me: deleted first "intermediates" folder [did not work] then deleted both .gradle and .idea folders
Problem solved :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error setting up RamDisk (using Win 10, gradle 7, Kotlin)

> 'other' has different root

Adding a symbolic link (admin rights required) solved the problem `mklink /D buildFolder R:\buildOutput`

Answer (score 0):

In my case. I checked the folder. .aab file was build their successfully. So, I ignored this error and enjoyed my coding

Answer (score -1):

First change path of past version to another drive:

[image]

And key store path and destination folder must be in same folder:

[image]

Comment: This is not true. Only the drives should be the same. Otherwise do an invalidate/restart.