# Error while creating a signed bundle in Android Studio - 'other' has different root

Tags: android

when i m trying to build signed bundle of my android app it showing following error.

```
Execution failed for task ':app:signReleaseBundle'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > 'other' has different root
```

[image]

i am trying to fix this issue from last 2 days but not getting solution. I have successfully build signed apk but not able to build signed aab file to publish in play store.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your gradle version to latest and also update android studio to latest.

If the problem persists still , maybe you can refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62089862/generate-signed-bundle-errors-while-building-bundle-file-other-has-different).